# Hyper disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of specified radius

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, regions

A very useful geometric and `Graphics3D` object is `Hyperplane[n,p]` which is an infinite hyperplane in arbitrary dimension $n$ with intrinsic dimension $n-1$ with normal vector `n` passing through point `p`.

I'd like to define a geometric object of the form `HyperDisk[n, p, r]`, which is a disk of radius $r$ and intrinsic dimension $n-1$, with its center on `p` and normal `n` embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This seems like the kind of clever geometric and graphics primitive that would be in *Mathematica* (I run version 11.3), but it is not.

What would be the most elegant way to define such a primitive, that would be compatible with `Hyperplane`, `InfinitePlane` and such?

Comment: Maybe an intersection of a `Hyperplane` with a `Ball`?

Comment: Oh... clever idea.  I like it.  Let me try playing with that....

Comment: Please publish the results.

Comment: Hmmm... it is proving more difficult than I thought.  I return to this tomorrow...

Comment: Got it!:  `HyperDisk[n_List, p_List, r_] := 
 Region[RegionIntersection[Hyperplane[n, p], Ball[p, r]]]`. That gives a `Region` but I want something for `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`.  I'll return to this later...